# Genesis 3:5 - 'as God' or 'as gods'?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, word-study

The KJV states :

> ... shall be as gods, knowing good and evil [Genesis 3:5]

Young's Literal states :

> ... as God, knowing good and evil [Genesis 3:5]

[Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/3-5.htm) states that the participle 'knowing' is

> V-Qal-Participle-Masculine Plural Construct

- What is the correct translation ?
- What **textual justification** is there for placing the emphasis on Adam and Eve's supposed 'knowledge' or upon God's supposed 'knowledge' ?
- Is the concept of a 'plural construct' in Hebrew the same as a 'collective noun' in English ?

Answer (score 3):

(...) It is unclear how the plural participle translated “knowing” is functioning. On the one hand, יֹדְעֵי (*yodÿ’e*) could be taken as a substantival participle functioning as a predicative adjective in the sentence. In this case one might translate: “You will be, like God himself, knowers of good and evil.” On the other hand, it could be taken as an attributive adjective modifying אֱלֹהִים (*’elohim*). In this case אֱלֹהִים has to be taken as a numerical plural referring to “gods,” “divine beings,” for if the one true God were the intended referent, a singular form of the participle would almost certainly appear as a modifier. Following this line of interpretation, one could translate, “You will be like divine beings who know good and evil.” The following context may favor this translation, for in 3:22 God says to an unidentified group, “Look, the man has become like one of us, knowing good and evil.” It is probable that God is addressing his heavenly court (see the note on the word “make” in [1:26](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?book=Gen&chapter=1&verse=26)), the members of which can be called “gods” or “divine beings” from the ancient Israelite perspective. (We know some of these beings as messengers or “angels.”) An examination of parallel constructions shows that a predicative understanding (“you will be, like God himself, knowers of good and evil,” cf. NIV, NRSV) is possible, but rare (see [Gen 27:23](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Gen%2027:23&book=gen&chapter=27&verse=23), where “hairy” is predicative, complementing the verb “to be”). The statistical evidence strongly suggests that the participle is attributive, modifying “divine beings” (see [Ps 31:12; Isa 1:30; 13:14; 16:2; 29:5; 58:11; Jer 14:9; 20:9; 23:9; 31:12; 48:41; 49:22; Hos 7:11; Amos 4:11](http://classic.net.bible.org/passage.php?search=Ps%2031:12;%20Isa%201:30;%2013:14;%2016:2;%2029:5;%2058:11;%20Jer%2014:9;%2020:9;%2023:9;%2031:12;%2048:41;%2049:22;%20Hos%207:11;%20Amos%204:11&passage=ps%2031:12;%20Isa%201:30;%2013:14;%2016:2;%2029:5;%2058:11;%20Jer%2014:9;%2020:9;%2023:9;%2031:12;%2048:41;%2049:22;%20Hos%207:11;%20Amos%204:11)). In all of these texts, where a comparative clause and accompanying adjective/participle follow a copulative (“to be”) verb, the adjective/participle is attributive after the noun in the comparative clause.

(Source: footnote 2**tn** appended to [Genesis 3:5](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=Genesis%203:5&book=genesis&chapter=3&verse=5#) NET)

In conclusion, here is the answer to the detailed questions.

- What is the correct translation ?

The translation given by NET is "... you [Adam and Eve] will be like divine beings who know good and evil"

- What **textual justification** is there for placing the emphasis on Adam and Eve's supposed 'knowledge' or upon God's supposed 'knowledge' ?

See a.q. footnote 2**tn**

- Is the concept of a 'plural construct' in Hebrew the same as a 'collective noun' in English ?

What we can say is that יֹדְעֵי (*yodÿ’e*) is definitely a plural participle. OTOH, אֱלֹהִים (*’elohim*) is the plural of אֱלוֹהַּ (*'elowah* - see [Strong's H433](https://www.blbclassic.org/lang/lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H433&t=KJV)). Referred to God Himself, the plural *’elohim* agrees with a verb in the singular. Referred to "divine beings" the plural *’elohim* works as a real plural, and agrees with a verb in the plural.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that in the days that the fallen angels slept with human women,that they certainly tried to present themselves as if they were God Himself but in reality as lower case "gods" to man kind false idles and creating false religions.  So yes I agree with the stance of heavenly congregation...knowing good and evil as God does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).